# Compress video file using FFMPEG and SDK in android

Tags: android, sdk, ffmpeg

I need to compress a video file before sending it to server.After searching I came to know that this can be done using FFMPEG,but this can only be done using **NDK**.
I want to compress the video using **java library** i.e. using SDK,Is that possible?

Comment: Actually I searched a lot for work around of this question. However, I could not find any helpful resource. So I think there is only one way which is ffmpeg by which you can compress videos.

Comment: But I read FFmpeg4Android doesn't need NDK as & C as well. Check this link : http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: Hi,I am trying to implement this:https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java,
But I am unable to compile FFMPEG and SOX files while running command "configure_make_everything.sh".Do you have any idea how can we do this?

Comment: Can i see logcat? In my case, it generates apk.

Comment: When I am trying to run fc.convertToMP4Stream(out, "0", 2, file1.toString(), new ShellCallback(){}. Which calls mFfmpegBin = installBinary(context, R.raw.ffmpeg, "ffmpeg", overwrite); Then my library from raw folder is not getting loaded and resulting in an exception.
May be I am missing some binary files like sox,ffmpeg,but I am not getting how to generate binary files.

Comment: Is it showing anytime in consol/logcat. If so, then post it.

Comment: I am able to make it work now but stuck with some other problem.Its not giving me the desired output,I am unable to get the file at specified location.The logcat output says:Unable to chmod [Ljava.lang.String;@41ed59e8: No such file or directory.
As int exitVal = process.waitFor(); returning a non zero value.

Comment: I'm not getting your error msg. Post logcat in proper format. Another thing is I don't understand why are you not posting your logcat. This is my 4th time saying same thing. If you really need help, then post logcat.

Comment: Below is the output which is returned when shellOut method of FfmpegController is called:

07-25 14:16:33.103: W/System.err(11425): concat non-zero exit: 1


07-25 14:16:34.822: I/System.out(11425): MIX>   libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
.
.
.

 MIX>   libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
 MIX>   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
 MIX>   libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
 MIX>   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
 MIX> [NULL @ 0xbfc3f0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '0'
 MIX> 0: Invalid argument

This is the final result I am getting without any exception.

Comment: I think, there something wrong in your last comment. Because I googled a lot but could not find any similar error msg. Still I'm telling you, post full log cat.